Weird files created with names like #855802604d9cc05c0e85b4d1e08f1bc8d72940a3#
I've been using doom emacs and magit along with tramp, and I noticed that copies of the files in the repo have been created in the same folder where the original files are, and they have these weird file names that start and end with the hash sign, and have a large number in between, eg. #855802604d9cc05c0e85b4d1e08f1bc8d72940a3#
The files are copies of the files I've been working with in the repo. I actually don't have a clue of what the reason might be, I've never seen anything like in git alone, so my first guess is that it might be something related to magit and emacs.
Any suggestion of the cause is appreciated, as of now I don't know where to start looking.
Thanks

That format, #*# is typical of Emacs auto-saves. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Control.html. Magit has it's own auto-save functionality. See: https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Automatic-Saving-of-File_002dVisiting-Buffers.html

I thought t could be something like this, but for me emacs auto-saves appended a ~ at the end of the file. Did it change for this #*# format, or I'm confusing things here?

In your particular example, it's probably something magit is doing. That filename looks like a hash to me.

foo~ is a backup of file foo, not an autosave. Do C-h i g(emacs) RET i Auto Save and read the Files subsection. Also i Backup files.

I agree, these look like hash names, I'll look it up to see if magit has some auto-save feature

I don't know what is doing that, but I can rule out that it is Magit (which I maintain).
